# Convexity of a rates Bermudan w.r.t strike

Tags: interest-rates, derivatives, american-options, convexity

Recently there was a nice question asked on convexity of American put w.r.t strike: [Convexity of an American put option](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54667/convexity-of-an-american-put-option)

Does the same hold for a Bermudan option in rates, where they underlyings are different swap rates? Say you have a Bermudan callable every one year from now for the next 5 years, and the underlyings are fixed-float swaps which have a tenor+maturity=10y (i.e, if I exercise at 1y, I enter into a 9 y swap, if I exercise at 2 y, I enter into an 8y swap..).

Comment: Will take a look in a bit. Thanks for writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bermudan (American) callable/swaption is convex with respect to the strike.

The payoff function of the Bermudan (American) callable/swaption is of the form, with implicit dependence on sample $\omega$,
$$g(t,K)=\big(a(t)-b(t)K\big)_+$$
where $t$ is the time the swap (interest) rate is set and $K$ is the strike. $g(t,K)$ is obviously convex with respect to $K$. Apply [the answer to Convexity of an American Option](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/54774/6686) and you obtain the desired result.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.